# Meu módulo de roteamento não encontra meu componente

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando aplicar lazy loading na minha aplicação, mas por algum motivo não está encontrado a importação do componente que eu faço no meu arquivo de roteamento do componente, retornando:

> Uncaught Error: Component CustofixoComponent is not part of any
>   NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

custofixo.module.ts:

```
    import { DialogConfirmacaoExclusaoModule } from './../../dialogexclusao/dialog-confirmacao-exclusao.module';
    //Importação de módulos angular
    import { MyMaterialDesignModule } from '../../../app.materialdesign.module';
    import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { NgxCurrencyModule } from "ngx-currency";
    import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { LoadingModule } from '../../loading/loading.module';
    import { NgxMaskModule } from 'ngx-mask'
    import { MostraToastService } from '../../../services/mostratoast.service';
    import { CustoFixoRoutingModule } from './custofixo.routing.module';
    //Importação de componentes do módulo
    import { CustofixoComponent } from './custofixo.component';
    import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material';
    import { CustosService } from '../../../services/custos.service';
    import { DialogConfirmacaoExclusao } from '../../dialogexclusao/dialog-exclusao.component';
    import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';
    import { svgInfoManModule } from '../../svgInfoMan/svgInfoMan.module';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CustoFixoRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        LoadingModule,
        MyMaterialDesignModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        DialogConfirmacaoExclusaoModule,
        NgxCurrencyModule,
        NgxMaskModule,
        svgInfoManModule,
      ],
      exports:[
        CustofixoComponent
      ],
      declarations: [CustofixoComponent],
      entryComponents:[DialogConfirmacaoExclusao],
      providers:[
        CustosService,
        MostraToastService,
        AuthService
      ]
    })

export class CustoFixoModule { }
```

custofixo.routing.ts: Aqui é onde o erro é gerado, por algum motivo ele não reconhece a importação do componente CustoFixoComponente. Será que estou esquecendo de algo?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustofixoComponent } from './custofixo.component';




    const custoFixoRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '', component: CustofixoComponent
        }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(custoFixoRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class CustoFixoRoutingModule {}
```

Meu root module roteamento:

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'dash', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
    { path: '', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/dashboard/bemvindo/bemvindo.module#BemVindoModule' },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/dashboard/bemvindo/bemvindo.module#BemVindoModule' },
    { path: 'custofixo', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/dashboard/custofixo/custofixo.module#CustoFixoModule' }
```

O módulo bem vindo funciona corretamente, porém já comparei os dois códigos e eles não possuem diferenças em relação aos módulos/roteamento

Comment: Acho que vc precisa declarar seu CustofixoComponent no seu CustoFixoRoutingModule para que ele consiga achar.

Comment: Declarar componente no meu módulo de roteamento? não faz muito sentido, ele já é declarado no módulo do componente

Comment: Seu módulo deveria declarar os componentes que ele usa... Fica meio redundante vc usar um componente dentro dele que vc usa em outro módulo que importa esse módulo. Talvez suas rotas devessem ser um componente ao invés de um módulo.